# Slick Slider - slick-current class is not moving when navigating if all slides are shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

I have a simple slider with Slick.js (https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

The slider arrows are hidden by default when all slide-items are shown because its not necessary to slide. So i use custom arrows with a click function that call `.slick('slickNext')` or `.slick('slickPrev')` and its working fine. But my issue is when all slide-items are shown and I call the functions to slide next or previous the `.slick-current` class on the active slide-item is not switching anymore.

My goal is that the `.slick-current` class still moves when I click the buttons.

An example: https://jsfiddle.net/0nprbj95/2/ Appreciate your help!

Comment: It would be helpful to see the options that you are setting when you initialize the Slick slideshow. If you don't already have it set, you might try `infinite: true` to allow your slides to move even if you're already displaying them all.

Comment: @EdLucas In the fiddle you can see the options but setting to infinite didnt solve my issue and even on infinite sliding the arrow function are disabled from slick when all items are visible

Answer (score 1):

One solution to ensure that Slick is moving the `.slick-current` class is to hold  the state of the current slide index and then use the `slick('goTo')` method to force Slick to move the class to this slide.

This may not give exactly the behavior that you want because Slick will still shift the slides in its "viewport", but you might be able to tweak the behavior from there.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var currentSlide = 0;
  var numSlides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide-item').length;

  $('.slider-items-wrapper').slick({
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      mobileFirst: true,
      infinite: true,
      arrows: false,
  });

  $('.button-prev').click(function(){
    // wrap to last slide when clicked on first slide
    currentSlide = (currentSlide - 1 + numSlides) % numSlides;
    $('.slider-items-wrapper').slick('goTo', currentSlide);
  });

  $('.button-next').click(function(){
    // wrap to first slide when clicked on last slide
    currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % numSlides;
    $('.slider-items-wrapper').slick('goTo', currentSlide);
  });
});
```

Full JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c3amxzk1/1/

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! But i need to work it out when infinite is false so that just the class of the slide items is toggling